# Tailwind CSS classes is not working with React, error "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app..."

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

Talwind CSS is not working with React. I have installed Tailwind CSS as per the documentation (https://v1.tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) and my code is below.

Can someone help me?

[Here is my browser pic of the inspect to understand my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5Ljd.png)

Here is my package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.18",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "postcss src/assets/css/tailwind.css -o src/assets/css/style.css",
    "start": "npm run build:css && react-scripts start ",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is my postcss.config.js

```js
  module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
  }
```

Below is my tailwind.config.js

```js
  module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  plugins: [
    // ...
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    // ...
  ]
}
```

Later, I edited my index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

//const App = require("./App");

ReactDOM.render(
    <App title="Heyy React Dev Tool"/>, document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I also edited my App.js like below

```
  import React from "react";
  import "./assets/css/style.css"

    function App({title}) {
      return (
          <div>
            <div className="bg-gray-600 text-white p-5 border">{title}</div>        
          </div>
      );
    
    }  
    export default App;
```

Last but now least these is my style.css file is generated

Style.css

````css
/*
! tailwindcss v3.0.18 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com
*//*
1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4)
2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width. (https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116)
*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  border-width: 0; /* 2 */
  border-style: solid; /* 2 */
  border-color: #e5e7eb; /* 2 */
}

::before,
::after {
  --tw-content: '';
}

/*
1. Use a consistent sensible line-height in all browsers.
2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
3. Use a more readable tab size.
4. Use the user's configured `sans` font-family by default.
*/

html {
  line-height: 1.5; /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */ /* 3 */
  tab-size: 4; /* 3 */
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"; /* 4 */
}

/*
1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
2. Inherit line-height from `html` so users can set them as a class directly on the `html` element.
*/

body {
  margin: 0; /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit; /* 2 */
}

/*
1. Add the correct height in Firefox.
2. Correct the inheritance of border color in Firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190655)
3. Ensure horizontal rules are visible by default.
*/

hr {
  height: 0; /* 1 */
  color: inherit; /* 2 */
  border-top-width: 1px; /* 3 */
}

/*
Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
*/

abbr:where([title]) {
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
}

/*
Remove the default font size and weight for headings.
*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}

/*
Reset links to optimize for opt-in styling instead of opt-out.
*/

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

/*
Add the correct font weight in Edge and Safari.
*/

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/*
1. Use the user's configured `mono` font family by default.
2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
*/

code,
kbd,
samp,
pre {
  font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct font size in all browsers.
*/

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/*
Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in all browsers.
*/

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/*
1. Remove text indentation from table contents in Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=999088, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201297)
2. Correct table border color inheritance in all Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935729, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195016)
3. Remove gaps between table borders by default.
*/

table {
  text-indent: 0; /* 1 */
  border-color: inherit; /* 2 */
  border-collapse: collapse; /* 3 */
}

/*
1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
3. Remove default padding in all browsers.
*/

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit; /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit; /* 1 */
  color: inherit; /* 1 */
  margin: 0; /* 2 */
  padding: 0; /* 3 */
}

/*
Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge and Firefox.
*/

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Remove default button styles.
*/

button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
  background-color: transparent; /* 2 */
  background-image: none; /* 2 */
}

/*
Use the modern Firefox focus style for all focusable elements.
*/

:-moz-focusring {
  outline: auto;
}

/*
Remove the additional `:invalid` styles in Firefox. (https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/2f9eacd9d3d995c937b4251a5557d95d494c9be1/layout/style/res/forms.css#L728-L737)
*/

:-moz-ui-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

/*
Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome and Firefox.
*/

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/*
Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/*
1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
*/

[type='search'] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px; /* 2 */
}

/*
Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
*/

::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
  font: inherit; /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct display in Chrome and Safari.
*/

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/*
Removes the default spacing and border for appropriate elements.
*/

blockquote,
dl,
dd,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
hr,
figure,
p,
pre {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

legend {
  padding: 0;
}

ol,
ul,
menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*
Prevent resizing textareas horizontally by default.
*/

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

/*
1. Reset the default placeholder opacity in Firefox. (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3300)
2. Set the default placeholder color to the user's configured gray 400 color.
*/

input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
  opacity: 1; /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af; /* 2 */
}

/*
Set the default cursor for buttons.
*/

button,
[role="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*
Make sure disabled buttons don't get the pointer cursor.
*/
:disabled {
  cursor: default;
}

/*
1. Make replaced elements `display: block` by default. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
2. Add `vertical-align: middle` to align replaced elements more sensibly by default. (https://github.com/jensimmons/cssremedy/issues/14#issuecomment-634934210)
   This can trigger a poorly considered lint error in some tools but is included by design.
*/

img,
svg,
video,
canvas,
audio,
iframe,
embed,
object {
  display: block; /* 1 */
  vertical-align: middle; /* 2 */
}

/*
Constrain images and videos to the parent width and preserve their intrinsic aspect ratio. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
*/

img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/*
Ensure the default browser behavior of the `hidden` attribute.
*/

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

*, ::before, ::after {
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
} 

'```
````

Comment: Thanks in advance for helping me?

Comment: Hello, can some one help me?

Comment: Is your app created using create-react-app?

Comment: @Terry,yes, I used these command npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: @Terry, Can i provide access to my github project?

Comment: I understood a bit now If you see the pic in that Element.styles{} is empty how to reflect on that

Comment: Did you follow this guide? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: yes, I followed these guide only, can I provide ACCESS TO MY git

Comment: Perhaps try creating a [mcve] on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/): it's impossible to troubleshoot based on the code here and to know what could've gone wrong. I have personally followed the guide before and my react app compiles without an issue with tailwind CSS. When you receive no response on a question for an extended period of time, it is likely an indicative of irreproducibility, lack of clarity, rather than a reflection of the helpfulness of the community.

Comment: @Terry, I forgot to inform you that , I deleted all the files in the src folder and created my own App.js and index.js in src folder. then I install the taiwindcss.

Comment: Here is my codesandboxlink: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-dew-bz89t

Comment: I think the issue is that codesandbox doesn't allow you to run the build scripts necessary to generate your pre-built tailwind CSS file :/ but based on the generated CSS file you've shared, it appears that tailwind has failed to detect uses. I have a feeling that's because in your code example, the file `tailwind.css` is not imported anywhere else. What happens if you import it in your React app and rebuild it?

Comment: @Terry, I never mind if you make any changes :). But, I changed it by importing tailwind.css instead of style.css. But raising the same thing. COuld you please edit, that's okay for me, its a sample project

Comment: and i also feel that could you please help me where to write the exact console.log() so, that I will get some info, even I tried these as well, please Terry, I am trying these from a week.

Comment: really thanks, I followed the guide, But I mistakenly, Instead of adding in  tailwind.config.js , I added in postcss.config.js. But thanks terry for your help atlost I solved it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've looked at your repo: and even though you said you followed [the guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app), you didn't. The issue boils down to not really following through the documentation properly.

This line is missing in your `tailwind.config.js` file, which causes tailwind to fail to detect class usage in all your `.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  // You are missing this block that defines what files tailwind should scan for usage
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Once you add this line your CSS should build properly:

[image]

---

Other signs that you didn't follow the guide properly:

- `tailwindcss` is listed as a dependency and not a devDependency
- Your `tailwind.config.js` file appears outdated. Are you sure you ran `npx tailwindcss init` properly? Are you sure that you are indeed running v3 of Tailwind CSS?

Answer (score 0):

check your index.js file you need to import ReactDom porperlt and also use it properlylike this

import ReactDom from "react-dom";

and this

import ReactDom from "react-dom";